# simple press permalink 404 error

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to use the Simple:Press forum plugin for WordPress.  If i go into my sites Settings/Permalinks and select anything other than Default, I get a 404 error whenever I try to access any of the forums or user profile.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Edit: I should add this is on a Windows machine and I have added the Web.config file which seems to work fine for other pages

Answer (score 0):

Is the proper .htaccess file being created when permalinks are enabled?  Could be a directory not writable issue.

Comment: Hi @jodan I should have mentioned that I'm doing this on a Windows machine. I have added a Web.config file and the re-write is working for other pages ok, it seems to be just the Simple:Press plugin having issues

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Wordpress you have, this might be the fix. It's a mod rewrite error.

Right click on the Bookmarklet, and change

> u=’+e(l.href)+’

to

> u=’+e(l.href.replace(///g,’\/’))+’

A quick work around is to delete part of the URL in the pop. Delete after

> http%3A%2F%2F

after the u=, up through the beginning of the domain for the website.